# Elastic search query working for numbers but not for strings

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jdbc-river

In my elastic search each doucument is in below format

```
{
      "_index" : "logstash-2014.08.11",
      "_type" : "apache-error",
      "_id" : "b9vZxg-wRbudJbsV6-vD-A",
      "_score" : 1.0, 
      "_source" : {
          "@version":"1",
          "@timestamp":"2014-08-11T02:07:26.000Z",
          "host":"127.0.0.1:49558",
          "type":"apache-error",
          "loglevel":"error",
          "clientip":"123.12.12.12",
          "errormsg":"htaccess: require valid-user not given a valid session, are you using lazy sessions?",
          "timestamp_submitted":"2014-08-14 19:25:11 UTC",
          "geoip":{"ip":"123.12.12.12"
              "country_code2":"US",
              "country_code3":"USA",
              "country_name":"United States",
              "continent_code":"NA",
              "latitude":38.0,
              "longitude":-97.0,
              "dma_code":0,
              "area_code":0,
              "location":[-97.0,38.0]
          }
      }
  }
```

i want to write a query where country_code2 in geoip is equal to US

when i try to run a query on geoip.ip the query is executing perfectly , works fine even for geo.latitude but when i try to run for geo.country_code2 i am not getting any results .
below is the query i am using

```
curl -XGET  http://abcd.dev:9200/_search?pretty=true -d 
{
    "query":{
        "term":{
            "geoip.ip":"123.12.12.12"
         }
     },
     "filter":{
         "range":{
             "@timestamp":{
                 "gte":"2014-08-12","lte":"now
             }
         }
     }
 }
```

the actually query for which the i am not getting any results

```
curl -XGET  http://abcd.dev:9200/_search?pretty=true -d 
    {
        "query":{
            "term":{
                "geoip.country_code2":"US"
             }
         },
         "filter":{
             "range":{
                 "@timestamp":{
                     "gte":"2014-08-12","lte":"now
                 }
             }
         }
     }
```

Comment: can you add the actual query on geo.country_code2?

Comment: @john i have added the actual query please check

Answer (score 0):

Use a [match query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html), instead of a term query.

```
{
    "query":{
        "match":{
            "geoip.country_code2":"US"
        }
    }
}
```

The match query will use the same analyzer to search on the field as what was used to index it.